# Saving data from PowerApps text field into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, powerapps

Does anyone know if it's possible to save data that a user inputs into a text field into a SQL Server table. We currently have data reading from SQL Server into our PowerApps app but we can't seem to figure out how we do the reverse. Someone mentioned using Flow but we're not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can save data from PowerApps into SQL Server by using the Patch() function.  For example by `Patch(MySQLtable, Defaults(MySQLtable), {MyTextColumn: MyTextInput.Text})`
where the expression is placed as the OnSelect property of a button and MyTextInput is a text input control in PowerApps.
Please see the [Patch function documentation](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-patch/)

Please also be aware of [current issues with SQL Server and PowerApps](https://baizini-it.com/blog/index.php/2017/09/28/powerapps-and-azure-sql-database-current-issues/)